# Second ToC with per-chapter author

Tags: table-of-contents, tocstyle

I am currently writing a larger document with multiple people. For grading purposes we need to specify one author per chapter/section/...

However, I would like to keep the real ToC clutter free, and thought about adding a second ToC at the end of the document, that would then have the author information as well.

The first idea was to use something like

```
\chapter[Chapter 1 {\normalfont\small\itshape The Author}]{Chapter 1}
```

This works, but oviously adds the "short" version to both ToCs. Is there a flag to ignore the short version, or any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279716/chapter-style-for-a-book-of-complied-articles?? (See the updated post at the end of my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below uses `etoc` only to allow multiple uses of `\tableofcontents`. Other classes (like, e.g.,  `memoir`) allow it directly contrarily to `report`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoc}% only so far to enable multiple uses of "\tableofcontents"
% maybe the document class already allows it.

\DeclareRobustCommand*\AUTHOR [1]{}
\newcommand\SHOWAUTHORS {%
\DeclareRobustCommand*\AUTHOR [1]{{\normalfont\small\itshape ##1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Chapter 1 \AUTHOR{The Author}]{Chapter 1}

\chapter[Chapter 2 \AUTHOR{The Other Author}]{Chapter 2}

\chapter[Chapter 3 \AUTHOR{Again The First Author}]{Chapter 3}

\SHOWAUTHORS
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

First TOC:

> [image: Blockquote]

Second TOC:

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: simple, easy to understand solution that does exactly what I needed - perfect! thank you