# Authblk for chapters? - Author and affiliations per chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, authblk, author

I'm trying to compile an `scrbook` and what I would like is to shon an author with affiliation for each chapter. The `authblk` package allows us to do this for the title.

Is there anyway to adapt it to chapters? I've tried different things, but most didn't work out. Does anyone maybe have a working piece of tex?

This is how I imagine it to work
(this is no working example, just an illustration:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\title{My Book}
\author{F. D. C. Willard}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
 \chapterauthor[1]{Don Joe}
 \chapterauthor[1]{F. D. C. Willard}
 \chapteraffil[1]{TeX Stackexchange School}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
 \chapterauthor[1]{John Doe}
 \chapterauthor[1]{Jane Doe}
 \chapterauthor[2]{Albert Einstein}
 \chapterauthor[3]{Pepe Frog}
 \chapterauthor[3]{Willy Wonka}
 \chapteraffil[1]{Harvard University}
 \chapteraffil[2]{Tex School}
 \chapteraffil[3]{High School 4C District}

 \end{document}
```

This should end up like this and additionally showing the author names and additionally a list of affiliations like this:
[image]

In the TOC I would just like to show a comma separated list of authors.

I've added the bounty b/c my tries just failed.

Comment: related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292522/second-toc-with-per-chapter-author/292593#292593 see accepted answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292593/4686

Comment: Thanks @jfbu - yes there are tons of those, but the affiliation seems to pose the real problem :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No package (apart hyperref), simple minded. Needs to be customized probably.

Note:  a solution without extra mark-up with `affils` environment is possible, but this one is easier to customize via `enumitem` for example for the list of affiliations.

#### edit

I have added variant using `\sffamily`, suppressing indentation of first paragraph following list of affiliations and controlling vertical space using `enumitem` for it.

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newif\ifnewauthor
\newauthortrue

\newcounter{affils}

\makeatletter
\def\chapterauthor[#1]#2{\ifnewauthor\else, \fi
       #2\textsuperscript{\hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#1]{#1}}%
       \ifnewauthor\newauthorfalse\gdef\chapterauthors{#2}\else
               \g@addto@macro\chapterauthors{, #2}\fi
       \ignorespaces % to remove end of line spaces from
                     % \chapterauthor[foo]{bar} input lines
}
\makeatother

\def\chapteraffil[#1]{\item[#1 --]%
    \refstepcounter{affils}%
    \label{authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#1}%
}

\newenvironment{affils}
   {\addtocontents{toc}{\chapterauthors\string\par}\begin{enumerate}}
   {\end{enumerate}\global\newauthortrue}


\begin{document}

\title{My Book}
\author{F. D. C. Willard}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
 \chapterauthor[1]{Don Joe}
 \chapterauthor[1]{F. D. C. Willard}
 \begin{affils}
   \chapteraffil[1]{TeX Stackexchange School}
 \end{affils}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
 \chapterauthor[1]{John Doe}
 \chapterauthor[1]{Jane Doe}
 \chapterauthor[2]{Albert Einstein}
 \chapterauthor[3]{Pepe Frog}
 \chapterauthor[3]{Willy Wonka}
 \begin{affils}
   \chapteraffil[1]{Harvard University}
   \chapteraffil[2]{Tex School}
   \chapteraffil[3]{High School 4C District}
 \end{affils}

\end{document}
```

TOC:

[image]

CHAPTERS:

[image]

[image]

---

Updated code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem, hyperref}
\newif\ifnewauthor
\newauthortrue

\newcounter{affils}

\makeatletter
\def\chapterauthor[#1]#2{\ifnewauthor\sffamily\else, \fi
       #2\textsuperscript{\hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#1]{#1}}%
       \ifnewauthor\newauthorfalse\gdef\chapterauthors{#2}\else
               \g@addto@macro\chapterauthors{, #2}\fi
       \ignorespaces % to remove end of line spaces from
                     % \chapterauthor[foo]{bar} input lines
}
\makeatother

\def\chapteraffil[#1]{\item[#1 --]%
    \refstepcounter{affils}%
    \label{authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{affils}
   {\addtocontents{toc}{\chapterauthors\string\par}%
    \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]}
   {\end{itemize}\par
    \global\newauthortrue
    \@nobreaktrue
    \aftergroup\normalfont}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{My Book}
\author{F. D. C. Willard}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

 \chapterauthor[1]{Don Joe}
 \chapterauthor[1]{F. D. C. Willard}
 \begin{affils}
   \chapteraffil[1]{TeX Stackexchange School}
 \end{affils}

No indentation for this first text paragraph.


\chapter{Chapter 2}

 \chapterauthor[1]{John Doe}
 \chapterauthor[1]{Jane Doe}
 \chapterauthor[2]{Albert Einstein}
 \chapterauthor[3]{Pepe Frog}
 \chapterauthor[3]{Willy Wonka}
 \begin{affils}
   \chapteraffil[1]{Harvard University}
   \chapteraffil[2]{Tex School}
   \chapteraffil[3]{High School 4C District}
 \end{affils}

And this text is with ``normal font'' settings.

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jfbu - this really helped me out. I'm making a book in latex..my first book, but hey I'm getting there. The code you wrote works perfect. I've changed it so the the authors show up as ssfamily in the toc. Unfortunately now the whole toc shows up like that ^^ - maybe a hint. I thought I could just add that in this line `{\addtocontents{toc}{\chapterauthors\string\par}`?

Comment: @nhck try `\addtocontents{toc}{{\sffamily\chapterauthors}\string\par}`

Comment: thanks - this Tex-Scripting language is mysterious sometimes ;-) Works like a charm. Imho this whole thing should be a package :-) An extension of authblk would be awesome.

Again: Thanks so much! You helped me a lot.

Comment: How would you handle multiple affiliations per author? If I just insert a comma separated list, the hyperlinking breaks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need it, here is a modification that allows to manage multiple affiliations by author

It uses the `tikz` package which allows to use the `\foreach` command.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifnewauthor
\newauthortrue

\newcounter{affils}

\makeatletter
\def\chapterauthor[#1]#2{\ifnewauthor\else, \fi
       #2\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {#1}{%
       \ifnum\xi=1 \textsuperscript{\hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.\x]{\x}}%
           \else \textsuperscript{\hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.\x]{,\x}}%
           \fi%
       }%
       \ifnewauthor\newauthorfalse\gdef\chapterauthors{#2}\else%
               \g@addto@macro\chapterauthors{, #2}\fi%
       \ignorespaces % to remove end of line spaces from \chapterauthor[foo]{bar} input lines
}
\makeatother

\def\chapteraffil[#1]{\item[#1 --]%
    \refstepcounter{affils}%
    \label{authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#1}%
}

\newenvironment{affils}
   {\addtocontents{toc}{\chapterauthors\string\par}\begin{enumerate}}
   {\end{enumerate}\global\newauthortrue}

\begin{document}

\title{My Book}
\author{F. D. C. Willard}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
 \chapterauthor[1,2]{John Doe}
 \chapterauthor[1,3]{Jane Doe}
 \chapterauthor[2,3]{Albert Einstein}
 \begin{affils}
   \chapteraffil[1]{Harvard University}
   \chapteraffil[2]{Tex School}
   \chapteraffil[3]{High School 4C District}
 \end{affils}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!