# Modifying author affiliations code to enable inclusion of multiple afiliations per author

Tags: chapters, authblk, author

I found this question: [Authblk for chapters? - Author and affiliations per chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383483/authblk-for-chapters-author-and-affiliations-per-chapter) which defines a very nice framework for including author affiliations in chapters in a TeX document. I want to tweak it slightly, to allow the optional inclusion of more than one affiliation per author.

I managed to do it by defining `\chapterauthormulti` like so:

```
\makeatletter
\def\chapterauthormulti[#1][#2]#3{\ifnewauthor\sffamily\else, \fi
       #3\textsuperscript{\hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#1]{#1},}%
         \textsuperscript{\hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.#2]{#2}}%
       \ifnewauthor\newauthorfalse\gdef\chapterauthors{#2}\else
               \g@addto@macro\chapterauthors{, #2}\fi
       \ifnewauthor\newauthorfalse\gdef\chapterauthors{#2}\else
               \g@addto@macro\chapterauthors{, #3}\fi
       \ignorespaces % to remove end of line spaces from
                     % \chapterauthor[foo]{bar} input lines
}
\makeatother
```

which allows me to add up to 2 affiliations and can be generalized in a straightforward is bulky way to more. This works, but seems very inelegant. Is there a cleaner way to modify that example to allow an arbitrary (within reason) number of affiliations to be added to each author in a single definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm 100% sure what you're looking for. But if I understand correctly, you can use a comma separated list.

First

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

Next, taking the code from your linked answer, modify the definition of `\chapterauthor`

```
\makeatletter
\def\chapterauthor[#1]#2{\ifnewauthor\else, \fi
   #2\affilscripts{#1}%<- Change is here
   \ifnewauthor\newauthorfalse\gdef\chapterauthors{#2}\else
           \g@addto@macro\chapterauthors{, #2}\fi
   \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
```

Then write a separate macro `\affilscripts` to print the superscripts

```
\newcommand{\affilscripts}[1]{%
  \let\supsep\relax
  \ifundef{\do}{\newcommand{\do}[1]{}}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \textsuperscript{\supsep%
     \hyperref[authaffil\the\value{chapter}.##1]
      {##1}}\def\supsep{,~}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
```

(Incidentally -- there's something odd here. It *shouldn't* need the `\ifundef{}{}{}`, but for some reason that I couldn't be bothered to track down, I was receiving "complaints" about `\do` being undefined, which I had to silence. It does no harm, but it's ugly. I'm probably messing up groups or something, as I often do.)

Then, say

```
\chapterauthor[1,2]{Jane Doe}
```

Will produce "Jane Doe" with superscript "1, 2", hyperlinked to the list of affiliations. You can have as many as you want.

Comment: Note that the `\chapterauthor` command you define needs to be enclosed in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to work

Comment: So it does, indeed!