# author chapter table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, authorindex

I am using the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

%%
% Kolumnentitel
%%
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } % Stil der Kopfzeile zurücksetzen
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % Stil der Kopfzeile 

% Page style
%\makepagestyle{mystyle}
%\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{\small\chapterauthor}{}
%\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\slshape\leftmark}{\thepage}
%\pagestyle{mystyle}

%%
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}

%%
% Dokumentenbeginn
%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* 
\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Trying to change it to, author should be the chapter: [image]

Comment: This looks very familiar what I have done some time ago! It's a changed version of    http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257109/31729

Comment: It's usual to link to a question/answer when code is 'stolen' and please clearify your post. I don't know what you are after here ....

Comment: you're right, it looks very familiar. Anyway, my problem is a little bit different. I want to change not only the table of contents, I want to change the chapter name "Kapitel1" to author name (Walter von der Vogelweide)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have seen some makechapterhead from you, can you answer this qeuestion?

Comment: @Johannes_B: ????

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, not even seen the answer. I guessed there would be none, since this appeared in the close review queue.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, I vtc because there was no feedback by the O.P. so my answer was apparently not was he wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is what you wanted: I've changed the code from another answer of mine ([Chapter style for a book of complied articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279716/chapter-style-for-a-book-of-complied-articles)) and reused it.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@chapter\chapter

\def\latex@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}



\newcommand{\NoNameAuthor}{Unknown}
\newcommand{\authortocname}{List of Authors}

\newcommand{\AuthorTocSectionDefaultOrder}{subtitle,author,date,journal,url} % Default sections 

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareAuthorChapterKey}{m}{%
  \define@key{authortoc}{#1}{%
    \expandafter\def\csname kvauthortoc#1\endcsname{##1}
  }%
  \define@key{authortoc}{#1style}{%
    \expandafter\def\csname kvauthortoc#1style\endcsname{##1}
  }%
}

\DeclareAuthorChapterKey{title}
\DeclareAuthorChapterKey{author}
\DeclareAuthorChapterKey{pagenumber}
\DeclareAuthorChapterKey{chapter}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \@ifundefined{kvauthortocauthor}{}{%
        \kvauthortocchapterstyle \kvauthortocauthor%
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      }%
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }
}




\NewDocumentCommand{\AddAuthorName}{mmm}{%
  \addtocontents{autoc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{#2}{}}%
  \addcontentsline{autoc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline\thechapter~#1}
}




\newcommand{\authortableofcontents}{%
  \chapter*{\authortocname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \latex@starttoc{autoc}%
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{somO{}}{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{authortoc}{author={\NoNameAuthor},#4}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@chapter*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@chapter[#2]{#3}
      \AddAuthorName{\kvauthortoctitlestyle{#2}}{\kvauthortocauthorstyle{\kvauthortocauthor}}{\kvauthortocpagenumberstyle{\thepage}}%
    }{% 
      \latex@chapter[#3]{#3}
     \AddAuthorName{\kvauthortoctitlestyle{#3}}{\kvauthortocauthorstyle{\kvauthortocauthor}}{\kvauthortocpagenumberstyle{\thepage}}%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\DefaultAuthorStyle}[1]{%
{\normalsize \itshape #1}
}

\newcommand{\DefaultChapterStyle}[1]{%
{\Huge \bfseries #1}
}



\newcommand{\DefaultPagenumberStyle}[1]{%
{\bfseries \color{blue} #1}
}

\newcommand{\DefaultTitleStyle}[1]{%
{\bfseries #1}
}


\presetkeys{authortoc}{authorstyle=\DefaultAuthorStyle, 
  titlestyle={\DefaultTitleStyle},
  pagenumberstyle=\DefaultPagenumberStyle,
  chapterstyle={\DefaultChapterStyle},
}{}



\begin{document}
\authortableofcontents
\tableofcontents


\chapter{The Fellowship of the Ring}[author={J. R. R. Tolkien}]

\chapter{The Two Towers}[author={J.R.R. Tolkien}, authorstyle={\color{red}}]

\chapter{The Return of the King}[author={J.R.R. Tolkien}, pagenumberstyle={\bfseries \color{brown}}]


\chapter[High Castle]{The man in the high castle}[chapterstyle={\Huge \bfseries \color{orange}},author={J. P. Dick}, pagenumberstyle={\bfseries \color{brown}}]
\blindtext[10]


\chapter{Stoner}[author={John Williams}]
\blindtext[10]


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]